# Removing background image from label in tornadofx

Tags: css, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I have two css classes on a tornadofx label bound to a SimpleBooleanProperty. One which has a background image and a blue border and one which has no background image and a yellow border.

Snippet from View containing label:

```
val switch: SimpleBooleanProperty = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)

label("my label"){
   toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style1, switch.not())
   toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style2, switch)
}
```

Snippet from UIAppStyle:

```
s(style1){
   textFill = Color.YELLOW
   maxWidth = infinity
   maxHeight = infinity
   alignment = Pos.CENTER

   backgroundImage += this::class.java.classLoader.getResource("img.png")!!.toURI()
   backgroundPosition += BackgroundPosition.CENTER
   backgroundRepeat += Pair(BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT)
   borderColor += box(Color.BLUE)
}
s(style2){
   textFill = Color.YELLOW
   maxWidth = infinity
   maxHeight = infinity
   alignment = Pos.CENTER
   borderColor += box(Color.YELLOW)
}
```

When `switch = false`, there is a background image and a blue border. When `switch = true`, there is the same background image and a yellow border. I'm not finding out how to get the background image to remove. Interestingly enough, if I add a different background image to `style2`, it changes correctly.

**Edit:** To remove two toggleClasses and introduce new strange problem:

```
class MyView : View(){
...
init{
   ...
   row{
      repeat(myviewmodel.numSwitches){
         val switch = myviewmodel.switches[it]
         val notSwitch = switch.not()
         label("my label"){
            addClass(UIAppStyle.style2)
            toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style1, notSwitch)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This code snippet does not work for me. However, if I add `private var throwsArray = mutableListOf<ObservableValue<Boolean>>()` as a field of MyView and add notSwitch to the array, then the same exact code works. It's almost as if notSwitch is going out of scope and becoming invalidated unless I add it to a local array in the class?

Comment: I'd guess that it's because how you store your "switches". If you change the item of the view model, then that switch binding is not updated, as it's connected to the switch in the list, not the list itself. This wouldn't be noticed if you put an item in the View Model before initializing your root. Also, since your code indicates a table view, just know items in rows change a lot, as rows are recycled.

Comment: I don't think its that because everything works for switch, just not switch.not(). I think the problem is stemming from creating the switch.not() within either row{}, repeat{}, or label{}. Maybe it's being disposed somehow from those lambdas exiting? I can work around it and make things work, I just don't understand it.

Comment: Would you mind making a minimal, runnable example that shows this issue? I often find that making the generalized runnable example helps me find the issue before I've posted the question. For the other times, minimal, runnable code snippets will help others find the problem.

Comment: @JCamacho I created a small demonstration project and posted to GitHub (https://github.com/adstotz/tornadofxtest). In building out this limited example, I've actually narrowed down to an issue where adding a "private val logger = KotlinLogging.logger{} to either the View or the ViewModel seems to break the functionality. You'll see my comment in TestView.

Comment: Going through it now, although it's a bit hard to untangle. While there many design issues, the thing that stands out to me is that you seem to think your gridpane will reflect changes in the view model's list of switches. You haven't used any sort of binding techniques so your grid will just show those original three Status objects. You also never reset the status value on reset, so even the original 3 status objects haven't changed. I'll keep looking at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited to do inverse of status**

Here is simple example of a working toggle class using your styling:

```
class TestView : View() {
    override val root = vbox {
        val status = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)

        label("This is a label") {
            addClass(UIAppStyle.base_cell)
            val notStatus = SimpleBooleanProperty(!status.value)
            status.onChange { notStatus.value = !it } // More consistent than a not() binding for some reason
            toggleClass(UIAppStyle.smiling_cell, notStatus)
        }
        button("Toggle").action { status.value = !status.value }
    }

    init {
        importStylesheet<UIAppStyle>()
    }
}
```

As you can see, the base class is added as the default, while styling with the image is in the toggle class (no `not()` binding). Like mentioned in other comments, the toggleClass is picky, additive in nature, and quiet in failure so it can sometimes be confusing.

FYI I got to this only by going through your [github code](https://github.com/adstotz/tornadofxtest) and I can say with confidence that the `not()` binding is what screwed you **in regards to the toggleClass behaviour**. Everything else causing an error is related to other problems with the code. Feel free to ask in the comments or post another question.

Comment: Appreciate your review. In your example, the image starts off and is toggled on. I need it in the reverse. I also have no idea why adding a logger to the class would affect the behavior as I indicated in the code.  I don't need gridpane to dynamically bind to the list of statuses so it's ok that the binding is happening to predetermined objects.

Comment: I updated my answer. It seems the `not()` binding is the faulty thing. I don't know why it seems to trigger only sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t understand why you want to have two different toggleClass for the same control. As you pointed out, the problem in your case is that when the backgroundImage is set, you need to set a new one in order to change it. But in your case, you only have to add the style without backgroundImage first and them set toggleClass with the style with backgroundImage. Like this:

```
label("my label"){
    addClass(UIAppStyle.style2)
    toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style1, switch)
}

button {
    action {
        switch.value = !switch.value;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** This ilustrate what I'm talking about in comments:

```
class Example : View("Example") {
    override val root = vbox {
        val switch = SimpleBooleanProperty(false)
        val notSwitch = switch.not()

        label("my label"){
            addClass(UIAppStyle.style2)
            toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style1, notSwitch)
        }

        button("One") {
            action {
                switch.value = !switch.value;
            }
        }

        button("Two") {
            action {
                notSwitch.get()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can put the notSwitch.get() in any action and without trigger that action it does the work. Check how I put it in the action of button Two, but without clicking that button even once, it works.

This is actually some kind of hack, in order to achieve what you want. But I don’t see the reason why my initial solution with true as default value for property  shouldn’t work.

Comment: I originally tried this and it works but in the reverse of what I need. I need the default state to contain the image and when the switch is toggled, remove it. So in your example, if I simply change to `toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style1, switch.not())` the image is not removed when the switch is toggled.

Comment: @Adam have you tried doing `addClass(UIAppStyle.style1)` and  `toggleClass(UIAppStyle.style2, switch)` instead? If I understand correctly, the default style should be in `addClass`.

Comment: @JCamacho if the background image is in the base class, then when I "add" a class through the toggleClass, I'm not sure how to specify in typesafe css to remove the background image. (part of the question I guess)

Comment: @Adam if you need the image to be the default state, the switch property value should be true by default.

Comment: @gredow isn't that what switch.not() is accomplishing? I need the image to disappear on an event that is changing that SimpleBooleanProperty to true. Is there any strange effect that .not() is having? I figured it would just bind the class to the inverse of the Boolean value.

Comment: @Adam My friend, should be obvious that my previous comment would work as I said, because is just doing what toggleClass always do. In your comment to my original answer you said: “I originally tried this and it works” but your problem was you need the opposite. Making switch property value to be true by default won’t change what toggleClass is doing, which is applying style1 when switch value is true and removing style1 when is false. So when switch.not() is not doing  that, is because is not the same I propose.

Comment: @Adam If you can afford the switch to be true by default them go for it; if you can’t, create another variable, like this:
`val notswitch = switch.not()
and them use notswitch instead of switch.not().

Comment: @Gredow. This is both interesting and confusing to me. The issue is with .not() I believe. If I create another SimpleBooleanProperty (notSwitch) within my ViewModel and update it through notSwitch.value to be the opposite of the switch (everywhere that switch gets updated), everything works. Alternatively, If I create val notSwitch = switch.not() it does not work. I think .not() is causing toggleClass to not get triggered by the updates is my best guess.

Comment: @Gredow After looking at .not(), it returns a BooleanBinding and toggleClass is overloaded to take either a Boolean or ObservableValue<Boolean>. BooleanBinding implements the ObservableValue interface so I'm just really confused why switch.not() is not working.

Comment: @Adam my bad. I forgot to tell you that you need to call notSwitch.get() in order to the BooleanBinding get validate. Since the reason why the switch.not() is not working is because is invalid, and that is not tornadofx related, I believe

Comment: @Gredow I see your suggestion of calling .get() prior to the toggleClass call changing switch.isValid from false to true, but it doesn't seem to have any effect for me.

Comment: @Gredow see my comment in the edit. Your answer has worked for me to most of the extent but in my exact situation, I think my root problem all along has been something else strange. Have you seen something like this?